# AS3 - something like arguments.caller?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there something that returns a reference to the object that called the function?

For example, I have..

```
public function getSquadLocation(squadID:int):Location {
//stuff
}
```

This gets called from other classes - for example:

```
getSquadLocation(selectedSquad);
```

where selectedSquad is a variable of the class that calls the function. I've being repeating this many times, would it be possible to specify the default value as something like...

```
public function getSquadLocation(squadID:int = arguments.caller.selectedSquad){
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't access the "caller" 'implicitly'. Quoting the [relevant page from the ActionScript 3 documentation by Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/arguments.html):

> Unlike previous versions of ActionScript, ActionScript 3.0 has no arguments.caller property. To get a reference to the function that called the current function, you must pass a reference to that function as an argument.

What you can do, and it would arguably be a "less volatile" alternative, is to simply pass the "caller" to a method *as an argument*, i.e. explicitly. There are many advantages to this approach, as you may discover in the long run:

- Porting the code to other platforms where function caller information is not exposed, is less troublesome.
- Passing required caller information explicitly as function arguments (on the stack) *may* yield more performance.
- Passing caller information explicitly to a function reads better as the dependency of the implementation on the caller is made explicit, assisting in readability and understanding of the code.